# Question about fixed-effects/time-effects model in R/plm

Tags: r, interaction, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have a few questions about using the plm package's models to get fixed effects and time effects. Here's a basic sketch of the code:

```
group <- c("Red","Red","Red","Blue", "Blue", "Green","Green","Green")
year <- c(2006,2007,2008,2006,2007,2006,2007,2008)
outcome <- c(1,2,3,6,8,6,7,9)
play <- data.frame(group,year,outcome)

play.fe <- plm(outcome ~ year,
           data=play, model="pooling",
           index = c("group", "year"),
           effect=NULL
           )
summary(play.fe)
play.fe2 <- plm(outcome ~ year,
           data=play, model="within",
           index = c("group", "year"),
           effect="individual"
           )
summary(play.fe2)
fixef(play.fe2)
```

play.fe2 drops one of the time period dummies, which makes sense since we already have "intercepts" in the group fixed effects, but I'd like it instead to keep all the dummies, but add the linear restriction that the time fixed effect coefficients sum to zero (which should work, since it will preserve degrees of freedom). Is this possible? I've looked into restrict.matrix, but haven't successfully gotten it to work.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if I need to add anything else/am not following any guidelines and I will fix it.

Comment: What are you trying to prove here?

Comment: Just trying to use the model to measure the impacts of the groups and the years on the outcome.

Comment: If you want to check whether there is sufficient within-variation, you need to focus on Rsquared. I am not sure why are you looking at coefficient on time dummies.

Comment: I'm not looking to see whether the impact is significant, but what the amount of that impact actually is.